# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api

i am completely new to REACT NATIVE and i got this error while i was working with api's and the api request through AXIOS won't show any data and here is my speculation "this is happening because I am using someone else's(of a person whos's course i dowloaded from UDEMY) api key and its quite old but if not pls help me sole this error and if u guys have a yelp acc can anyone share there up to date api key ?
thanks

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default axios.create({
    baseURL:'http://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses',
    headers:{
        Authorization:
        "Bearer 12cmhfZezRI6ZkcHWNYKoDpiaro1zlqUjwkA7nVxnWzryiTwFDk35PJiucoLhjjFY9ECD8GTBGaHBg5yv5YDLiszKQx8EMvm30plyOUWoHQOnYFjLozpYnZOx-UsXXYX",
    }
})
```

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import SearchBar from "../../components/SearchBar";
import Yelp from "./api/Yelp";

const SearchScreen = () =>{
    
    const [term , setTerm] = useState('')
    const [results, setResults] = useState([])

    const searchApi = async () =>{
        const response = await Yelp.get('/search',{
            params: 
            {
                limit: 50,
                term : term,
                location: 'san jose'
            }
        })
        setResults(response.data.businesses)

    }

    return(
        <View>
            <SearchBar 
            term={term} 
            onTermChange={(newTerm)=> setTerm(newTerm)}
            onTermSubmit={()=> searchApi()}
            />
            <Text>
                Search Screen !
            </Text>
            <Text>We have found {results.length} results</Text>
        </View>
    )
}


const Styles = StyleSheet.create({

})

export default SearchScreen;
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your source code, it seems your `Auth Token` is expired. Please check that.

Comment: i have similar issue, your auth token is expired thank you @kevin Macwan